# How to only barely use the bandwidth available to your program

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, language-agnostic, network-programming

I am making a program that will download a bunch of different items. My language has cheap concurrency, so I first thought that I could download them all at once. Problem is [using concurrency you don't have is bad](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000022.html). If I tried downloading them all at once, the user would have to wait for all of them before getting any of them.

Let's say that you are downloading 10 items that can be downloaded at 7 mb/s, and you have 20 mb/s of download speed. The program should start downloading only the first **three** items, and will only start downloading new items once old items have finished and there is bandwidth. Note also that in general the items won't have the same download speed.

If I had some programmatic way to check network saturation, this would be easy (just check if its saturated before spawning new threads.)

Comment: Do yu=ou know the total download speed in advance?

Comment: @PetrPudlák I do not.

Comment: @PyRulez Then this isn't going to be a simple problem to solve.  You'll have to start downloads individually until you hit a cap, which means you'll have to decide what it means to hit a cap.  At that point you'll know your bandwidth, but knowing the DL speed of each item is going to be more difficult.  If they're all coming from the same server and have roughly the same DL speed then you can just average them and assume, but if they're all different then it's going to be a more difficult balancing act.

Comment: Unless you have a priori knowledge about the network (and other users of it!) around you, this is close to impossible (ie: your program cannot automatically test and probe the available network resources).

Comment: I guess one option could be to monitor the TCP connections and when latency increases, you'd stop spawning new downloads and wait until it decreases again. But then again, you need to know what latency is considered OK and which latency means you're over the threshold. I'd say that good alternatives would be: (1) let the user give the top speed threshold and act accordingly, or (2) just let the user give the number of simultaneous network connections.

Comment: @LaszloValko Why is this hard? Why can't my program know when there is no network left?

Comment: @PetrPudlák How would I even control how much my program uses?

Comment: @PyRulez It is hard because your program is not the only user of the network link. Sometimes a DSL is shared among many devices and multiple users. Even in the same PC, what if the user starts browsing during the download? What if they receive an email with a largish attachment? What if the antivirus starts updating itself at that moment? Etc.

Comment: Network saturation *isn't* a locally defined metric. What if the local machine has tons of bandwidth to the next upstream node but that node is choked to 20Kb/s. You can't solve this problem locally. You can't even solve this problem remotely. The network latency/throughput aren't (generally) within your control so you shouldn't try to build systems that assume they are.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oh, I get it now. I thought it would be simple.

Comment: [Section 8.1.4 of the HTTP/1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4) says a “single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than *2 connections* with any server or proxy.” (emphasis mine).  The reasoning behind that soft limit follows for your case too - a greater number parallel connections can cause things to get overloaded. Many programs support multiple parallel downloads (examples are [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/)) but lots of those default to 2-4 connections and the user has to manually increase the number.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in the comments, you can't do this well enough to make any guarantees. But, suppose you want to do your best, anyways.

There are two parts to this problem:

1. Determine the bandwidth available.
2. Control the bandwidth being consumed.

Roughly controlling the bandwidth consumed can be accomplished in a user space program by limiting the rate at which you read from the socket. The TCP/IP stack will notify the other end of the connection that the queue is is maintaining on your application's behalf has gotten full, and nothing more will be sent. A convenient way of implementing that rate limiting is with [token buckets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket).

Quick token bucket implementation:

```
 int bucket = 0;
 start_thread({ while(transfer_in_progress) {
                    bucket += bytes_per_second_limit;
                    sleep(1);
                });
 while(transfer_in_progress) {
    bytesread = read(socket, buffer, min(bucket, buffersize), );
    bucket -= bytesread;
 }
```

If `bytes_per_second_limit` is set to roughly the bandwidth available, expressed in bytes/second, then that should read as fast as the connection allows. If the connection is faster, you'll be limited to `bytes_per_second_limit`. If the connection is *slower*, then `bucket` will grow forever, at a rate proportional to the difference between the speed limit, and the available bandwidth.

Hmm!

If you run another thread, and keep an eye on `bucket`, you can watch for two conditions:

1. If `bucket` is always 0, then there is more bandwidth available, and you can increase `bytes_per_second_limit`, limited perhaps by your most recent best guess for available bandwidth (from #2). Or start an additional download.
2. If `bucket` is larger than the last time you looked, and the last few seconds of data points appear to indicate continuing growth (maybe do a linear regression; whatever you like), the rate of that growth expressed in bytes/second is how much you can reduce `bytes_per_second_limit` by in order to match your download rate with the available bandwidth.

The problem with all this is that there is no guarantee your bandwidth will stay constant. The thread monitoring `bucket` might bounce back and forth between increasing the rate, and limiting it. I'd suggest you start by averaging over at least 10 or 20 seconds before making rate limit changes.